# Safari convert '' (empty string) to 0 in URL

Tags: javascript, url, safari, mobile-safari

We found unexpected behavior with URL object in safari. When you convert URL to string it will add `0` port(`:0`) if you set the port property to an empty string. e.g.

```js
let url = new URL('https://www.example.com');
url.port = '';
console.log(url.toString()); // expected "https://www.example.com/", actual "https://www.example.com:0/"
```

[image]

From [spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-url-port) I see:

> If the given value is the empty string, then set context object’s URL's port to null.

So is it bug or feature in safari?

Comment: One person's feature is another person's bug `:-)`.  By the way, I checked in Chrome and it doesn't happen there.

Comment: Seems to me like a bug. Empty string should not be defaulted to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also run into this. It's [Web Kit Bug 127958](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=127958) and at the time of writing almost 6 years old. The obvious workaround is to simply avoid assigning empty strings.

For example, if you have code like this:

```js
template = new URL( template_url );
result = new URL( input_url );
for ( part in template ) {
    result[ part ] = template[ part ] ?? result[ part ];
}
```

You could instead do this:

```js
template = new URL( template_url );
result = new URL( input_url );
for ( part in template ) {
    if ( template[ part ] && template[ part ] !== result[ part ] ) {
        result[ part ] = template[ part ];
    }
}
```